# svg hover highlight all countries in a continent

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have [this world map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:World_map_(Miller_cylindrical_projection,_blank).svg). I know how to make each individual country highlight when I hover over it, but I want *all* countries in a continent to highlight when I hover over any country in that continent.

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried and/or a snippet to demonstrate your attempt. This will also better help others who are trying to assist you.

Comment: I don't have any. I've been trying to find something online that will show me how to do what I'm thinking of, but haven't been able to find anything. That's why I came here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That world map isn't organized by much that I can tell. There are [digraph country codes](https://immigration-usa.com/country_digraphs.html) that are added as classes (PE: for Peru). You'll have to go through some resource of all digraphs or see if you find something that already indexes them by continent. This is necessary to create a mapping so you know which classes correspond to which continents.

Then you can set up rules such that if some country is highlighted then you know what other countries compose are apart of the same continent and can highlight those.

```
const countryToContinent = {
    'CA': 'North America',
    'US': 'North America',
    // ...
};
const continentToCountries = {
    'North America': ['US', 'CA', 'MX', // ...],
    // ...
};
const landElements = document.getElementsByClassName('land');
landElements.forEach(land => {
    land.addEventListener('hover', event => {
        let continent;
        land.classList.forEach(className => {
            if(className !== 'land'){
                if(countryToContinent.hasOwnProperty(className)){
                    continent = countryToContinent[]
                }

            }
        });
        // this is just to be careful, there are a lot of svgs in there
        if(continent){
            // remove previously highlighted countries/continents
            const alreadyHighlightedCountries = document.getElementsByClassName('highlight-block');
            alreadyHighlightedCountries.forEach(highlightedCountry => {
                highlightedCountry.remove('highlight-block');
            });
            const countriesToHighlight = continentToCountries[continent];
            countriesToHighlight.forEach(country => {
                const countrySvg = document.getElementsByClassName(country);
                if(!countrySvg.classList.has('highlight-block')){
                    countrySvg.add('highlight-block');
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Separately have this in your css

```
.highlight-block {
    fill: red !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm trying to get it to work, but I'm still a newbie. What goes in the space occupied by [...land.classList]? I'm assuming because of the ellipses that I'm supposed to put something there that is unique to my coding designations. Also, are there any other items like that, which I need to insert my own designations rather than using the ones you've used?

Comment: Nothing goes in there, that's a syntax to turn something into an array (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_array_literals). The reason I used it there is because `classList` is a `DOMTOkenList`, not an array (so it wouldn't have the `.forEach` method). That syntax converts it to an array.

Comment: Although, I just checked and `DOMTokenList` does have `.forEach`. Just edited the above to fix that.

Comment: To answer the rest of your question, the `countryToContinent` and `continentToCountries` are the only two areas you should have to fill out. The styling is also entirely up to you. I just went with red so it popped out.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the explanation. I'll see if I can get it to work.

Comment: No problem. Also just to help test this out, you could try with just a couple of countries at first to verify it has the intended behavior. Afterward you could start to spend time fleshing out those objects. There are a lot of countries so it might be a tedious task, unless you can find an easy resource with that already populated.

Comment: For some reason, I can't get it to work. I copied and pasted it from above into the code, just above the final </svg> tag. I also copied and pasted the CSS just as it is above. I also tried it with and without the tags <script> and </script> (do I use them or not?). When I hover over US and Canada, they don't change color, so I can't see if they're doing it in conjunction with each other, or separately. I've also checked the CSS to see if anything's overriding the CSS you provided, and there's nothing that would do that.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I have not always found this site to be accommodating to people who don't know much about coding.